# Verificar existência de arquivo na web

Tags: java, android, web-service

Seguinte, tenho um app Android, este aplicativo quer verificar a existência de uma imagem na web para poder carregar pelo Picasso, caso a imagem não exista num endereço exemplo www.algumacoisa.com/img/imagem5.png vou mostrar uma mensagem. Então o que preciso é validar a imagem(arquivo) antes de carregar, ou tentar carregar e se não existe me informar para que eu posso definir uma mensagem. Acho que está bem explicado. Não nessesariamente deve ser uma imagem, ou usando o Picasso.

Código:

Verificação se existe um arquivo no endereço www.lojaimpacto.com.br/img/foto05.png

```
if(arquivo existe){

        iv_xml01_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_xml01_logo);
        Picasso.with(lista_fones.this)
                .load(www.lojaimpacto.com.br/img/foto05.png)
                .resize(300, 155)
                .centerInside()
                .into(iv_xml01_logo);

} else {

 System.out.println("Arquivo não existe");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fabricio,

Há duas maneiras de fazer isso, eu prefiro especialmente a primeira. Você não precisa fazer um "teste manual" da existência do arquivo, o próprio Picasso, caso não consiga carregar a imagem, irá lhe informar que não foi possível carregar e isso poderá significar que houve falha na internet, ou que o arquivo não existe. Se não houver distinção entre esses tipos de erros para você faça como demonstrado no código abaixo.

Primeiro, isso pode ser feito através do Builder:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
        {
            // MENSAGEM AQUI!
        }
    });
    builder.build().load(URL).into(imageView);
```

Observe o método `onImageLoadFailed()`, será nele que você irá incluir o código a respeito da mensagem de erro que você comentou que gostaria de exibir.

Se você não quiser usar o Builder, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(fileImage)
                .into(holder.mImageEvidence, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                       // OK! ARQUIVO ENCONTRADO E CARREGADO!
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // MENSAGEM AQUI!
                    }
                });
```

Qualquer dúvida, deixe um comentário para poder esclarecer melhor.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public static boolean exists(String URLName){
    try {
      HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
      HttpURLConnection con =
         (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
    }
  }
```

Se o status retornado for igual a [200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#200) significa que o arquivo existe.

Answer (score 0):

Vou chutar que você tem uma função que chamada confereArquivo() e ele define o booleano 'arquivo_existe' para 'true' quando o encontra. Dentro de confereArquivo() você deve fazer a requisição e pegar a resposta, pode ser um httpRequest, se o retorno for 404, por exemplo, você já sabe que não há nada. Enfim, há outras formas de checar se o caminho tem algo, se é uma imagem, etc. Toda essa lógica deve estar dentro desse confereArquivo(). Sem fazer a chamada e analisa-la é impossível saber se o arquivo está lá ou não. Geralmente o status retornado = 200 significa que o arquivo existe, mas ainda assim pode dar falha no carregamento ou não ser fato uma imagem (pode não ser o caso de sua APP).